# Should we remove instances of Careers and replace with jobs

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

For example, asking company x a question:

[image]

Comment: Should be changed to "CV".

Comment: @Shog9 - I'd eliminate the word profile as well.  Profile to me is settings specific to my account.

Comment: Right - "Careers profile" should be replaced with "CV".

Comment: @Shog9 perfect, sounds right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've replaced "Careers profile" with "CV" in this particular string. We will also review copy across Careers and make similar updates where appropriate in the near future.